# Updating html table with new php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to refresh my table when the user clicks the button. This is because when the user clicks the button that row will be moved to the next table. (Not in this code example to make it simpler). How the tables are created are with the php code which executes in index code.php. Indexcode.php creates the variable $waiting which is then fetched in index.php and used to populate the table. When the button is clicked a request is sent to indexcode.php which updates the mysql tables. This is why I want to refresh the tables to display the new updated information. I have tried quite a few ways but to no avail.

index.php

```
<html>
<style>

<?php include 'table.css'; ?>
</style>
<?php include 'indexcode.php'; ?>


<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function orderPacked(val) {

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'indexcode.php',
       data: "packed=" + val,
       success: function(){
       var container = document.getElementById("yourDiv");
       var content = container.innerHTML;
       container.innerHTML= content;
       }
       });

}

</script>
<h1> <center> Warehouse </center></h1>
<p><center>This is for warehouse use</center></p>
<body>

<h2 class="text-waiting">These orders need to be packed</h2>
<body>

<table id="wtable" class="waiting-table" cellpadding="11"><tr>.   
<th>Order ID</th><th>Customer</th><th>Vendor</th><th>Address</th>.   
<th>Cart_ID</th><th>Cart</th><th>Checked</th></tr>

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($waiting)){
?>
<tr>
<?php
echo '<td>',$row[0],'</td>';
echo '<td>',$row[1],'</td>';
echo '<td>',$row[3],'</td>';
echo '<td>',$row[7],'</td>';
echo '<td>',$row[2],'</td>';
echo '<td>',"items",'</td>';
?>
<td>
<button onclick="orderPacked('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')" id="button"     
name="packed" >Packed</button>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

indexcode.php

```
...
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sale WHERE wh_state =     
'waiting'");

$stmt->execute();

$waiting = $stmt->get_result();


$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sale WHERE wh_state = 'packed'");

$stmt->execute();

$packed = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();
// define variables and set to empty values
$orderErr = "";
$order = "";

    if (empty($_POST["packed"])) {

                 $orderErr = "Error";
       else {

        $orderp = test_input($_POST["packed"]);

        // update the state of the sale
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE sale SET wh_state = 'packed' WHERE id = '{$orderp}'");
        $stmt->execute();

        $waiting = $stmt->get_result();

        $stmt->close();

    }       

   }
...
```

Comment: You can fetch the updated row from the table, return it and in the same AJAX you can append the data to existing table.

Comment: How would I append the data to the existing table inside the javascript function? (If I understand you correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when creating table in php.make a id for every row.
get the result from ajax response(update row).so you can update the row dynamically with the id with updated data with javascript.

`

```
<?php
      echo "<tr id='id_".$row[0]."'>";
      echo '<td>',$row[0],'</td>';
      echo '<td>',$row[1],'</td>';
      echo '<td>',$row[3],'</td>';
      echo '<td>',$row[7],'</td>';
      echo '<td>',$row[2],'</td>';
      echo '<td>',"items",'</td>';
      ?>
      <td>
      <button onclick="orderPacked('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')" id="button_<?php 
      echo $row[0]; ?> "     
         name="packed" >Packed</button>
      </td>
      </tr>
 <?php } ?>`
```

and also make sure to use unique id's for html elements.